# Squared transformations, distribution functions

Tags: statistics, transformation

$Y = X^2$

$f_{X}(x) = 1$

Find the PDF of $Y$.

$$f_{Y}(y) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\left[f_{X}\left(\sqrt{y}\right)+f_{X}\left(-\sqrt{y}\right)\right]$$

Right?

But what sense does the term $f_{X}(\sqrt{y})$ make, considering $f_{X}(x) = 1$?

Comment: What is the PDF of X, because that formula doesn't look right. How did you derive it?

Comment: The PDF is fx = 1. It was given.

Comment: f(x) = 1 isn't a PDF unless you specify the support. You could have 1. Degenerate: f(x) = 1 if x = c, f(x) = 0 otherwise. You could also have 2: Uniform: f(x) = 1 if a <= x <= b (where b - a = 1), f(x) = 0 otherwise. In this case, there infinitely many densities that satisfy the equation. I did a bit of digging, and this formula you showed is correct, but doesn't actually require that you specify a PDF, thus to actually answer your question, it's necessary to know what the support of X is.

Comment: X varies between 0 and 1 but doesnt attain the endpoints. Maybe it's a typo from the lecturer.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like X is a uniform(0,1) RV. See my (forthcoming) answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is a continuous $\text{Unif}(0,1)$ RV, we have that

$f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

As noted in the comments above, the formula you provided works for any continuous random variable. That is, if $Y = X^2$, then for $y \geq 0$,

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\left[f_X(\sqrt{y}) + f_X(-\sqrt{y})\right],\\
\end{align}
As for your question, what does the term $f_X(\sqrt{y})$ actually mean? Since $0 \leq X \leq 1$, we have that $0 \leq Y \leq 1$ as well, and $f_X(\sqrt{y}) = 1$ along the entire support of $Y$. That makes the above equation

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\left[1 + f_X(-\sqrt{y})\right],\\
\end{align}

I'll let you tackle the derivations for $f_X(-\sqrt{y})$ on your own, but you should get that it's equal to zero along the entire support of $Y$.